# Increment Android build number in Continuous Integration

Tags: android, git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using Android Studio, Gradle, git.

On every push to the master branch I want to build a new App version that's uploaded to the Alpha channel of the Google Play Store. For this I need to increase the versionCode of the App for every build.

For this I seem to have several choices:

1. Increase the number during the Jenkins build and  push the changed file back to the repo.

   - I don't like the idea of having my build server doing pushes/commits.
2. Increasing the number with a git hook.

   - I like the idea even less to use git for modifying files. If I'm on vacation who (in the rest of the team) would ever find this and know what to do with it?
3. Have a file on another server (which the build server can access directly) wherin the current version is saved. Gradle will access it, increase it & save it again.

   - This seems 'fragile' but at least I could have an easy 'increaseVersion' task that is only executed on the server. And if it breaks (if we move servers or something) it's fairly easy to repair.

Currently, I like 3 the best.

Does anybody have a definite way of doing it?

Comment: If you ever want to rebuild from a tag or build a branch, it's helpful to have the version in source control alongside the code.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of that. I don't think this would be critical (because I want to Tag each release), but it sure could be annoying at some point.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use none of the above — like you, I don't want to alter the repo for each build, nor any files.

Jenkins has an always-increasing value for each build, exposed via the `BUILD_NUMBER` environment variable.

In Gradle, I generate the `versionCode` value programmatically at build time, using the `BUILD_NUMBER` value to ensure that the `versionCode` is always higher than the previous build.

A snippet of my `build.gradle`:

```
// Used to set the package version name and version code
ext.versionMajor = 1
ext.versionMinor = 2

android {
  defaultConfig {
    versionName computeVersionName()
    versionCode computeVersionCode()
  }
}

// Will return "1.2" in this example
def computeVersionName() {
    // Basic <major>.<minor> version name
    return String.format('%d.%d', versionMajor, versionMinor)
}

// Will return 120042 for Jenkins build #42
def computeVersionCode() {
    // Major + minor + Jenkins build number (where available)
    return (versionMajor * 100000)
             + (versionMinor * 10000)
             + Integer.valueOf(System.env.BUILD_NUMBER ?: 0)
}
```

So I only need to update the two values at the top when making a release build.  For all other build types, I can let Gradle/Jenkins automatically set the `versionCode` and then [upload to Google Play](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin).

This also means, for any alpha version listed on the Play Store, or by inspecting an APK, I can see straight away which Jenkins build it came from, and from there the git commit.

Comment: So when you're happy with your alpha version (stemming from a dev branch), you merge to master branch, increase the version and push the master branch? If possible I would like to get rid of the manual increasing even of major versions. But your 'computeVersionCode' is a very good idea for versioning dev versions. Maybe I will settle for having a git hook telling you, you didn't increase the version... (at least you won't have to wait for jenkins / the upload to fail)

Comment: No, I only alter the major/minor versions for a production release. For alphas/betas, the version name/code are unimportant (though I include `BUILD_NUMBER` (or git SHA1) in the `versionNameSuffix`, so I end up with "1.2a42", for example). I control alpha/beta releases via git tags, so I can create a build at any point, without having to merge to master.

Comment: Doesn't Google Play give an error when you upload something with an old/already used version code? At least in the Beta channel I'm getting that error.

Comment: Sure it does. But the whole point of this answer was to show that each build *automatically* gets a new `versionCode` value that is higher than any previous build. For the Gradle script above, Jenkins build #42 would produce an APK with `120042`, and build #43 would have `120043` as its `versionCode`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment, thanks.

Comment: @Christopher I alway get System.env.BUILD_NUMBER as null